# See lots of clr!CLRSemaphore::Wait in call stack

Tags: c#, multithreading, debugging, threadpool, windbg

We see lots of callstack like the below, may I know what's conditions \situation would happens this?

```
OS Thread Id: 0x48654 (559)
Current frame: ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0xa
Child-SP         RetAddr          Caller, Callee
00000020a76cf480 00007fffd4ea1118 KERNELBASE!WaitForSingleObjectEx+0x94, calling ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject
00000020a76cf520 00007fffce50ce66 clr!CLRSemaphore::Wait+0x8a, calling kernel32!WaitForSingleObjectEx
00000020a76cf5e0 00007fffce50d247 clr!ThreadpoolMgr::UnfairSemaphore::Wait+0x109, calling clr!CLRSemaphore::Wait
00000020a76cf620 00007fffce50d330 clr!ThreadpoolMgr::WorkerThreadStart+0x1b9, calling clr!ThreadpoolMgr::UnfairSemaphore::Wait
00000020a76cf6c0 00007fffce5de8b6 clr!Thread::intermediateThreadProc+0x7d
00000020a76cfb40 00007fffce5de89f clr!Thread::intermediateThreadProc+0x66, calling clr!_chkstk
00000020a76cfb80 00007fffd60613d2 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x22
00000020a76cfbb0 00007fffd7be5454 ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x34
OS Thread Id: 0x3bd4c (560)
Current frame: ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0xa
Child-SP         RetAddr          Caller, Callee
00000020a774e910 00007fffd4ea1118 KERNELBASE!WaitForSingleObjectEx+0x94, calling ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject
00000020a774e9b0 00007fffce50ce66 clr!CLRSemaphore::Wait+0x8a, calling kernel32!WaitForSingleObjectEx
00000020a774ea70 00007fffce50d247 clr!ThreadpoolMgr::UnfairSemaphore::Wait+0x109, calling clr!CLRSemaphore::Wait
00000020a774eab0 00007fffce50d330 clr!ThreadpoolMgr::WorkerThreadStart+0x1b9, calling clr!ThreadpoolMgr::UnfairSemaphore::Wait
00000020a774eb50 00007fffce5de8b6 clr!Thread::intermediateThreadProc+0x7d
00000020a774ec30 00007fffd7c00c75 ntdll!RtlpLowFragHeapAllocFromContext+0x355, calling ntdll!memset
```

Comment: 0:030> !do 0000001fc0a80fe8 
Name:        System.Runtime.Remoting.Contexts.Context
MethodTable: 00007fffcd2ae6c8
EEClass:     00007fffccd74ad8
Size:        104(0x68) bytes
File:        C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c5619                                                                                                                     BTW, We also see the thread context is System.Runtime.Remoting.Contexts.Context

Comment: Just based on function names in the call stack, looks like an idle worker thread - one waiting for work to arrive.

Comment: It is an entirely normal state for a threadpool thread, it is waiting for work to do.  If you see a lot of them then something went wrong earlier, you had too many threadpool requests that took too long to complete.  The upper limit on the number of active TP threads is very high.  Beyond balancing the work load better, the ideal solution of course, the Q&D fix is calling ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads().

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned by [@Harry Johnston](https://stackoverflow.com/users/886887/harry-johnston) in the comments already, these are worker threads of a thread pool that have nothing to do.

The following example can be used to replicate such stacks. It will create 12 threadpool worker threads and when the debugger breaks, they are all in idle state as seen by you.

The code is based on Microsoft's [Fibunacci threadpool example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt679040.aspx):

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

public class Fibonacci
{
    public void ThreadPoolCallback(object threadContext)
    {
        FibOfN = Calculate(N);
        DoneEvent.Set();
    }

    public int Calculate(int n)
    {
        if (n <= 1) return n;
        return Calculate(n - 1) + Calculate(n - 2);
    }

    public int N { get; set; }
    public int FibOfN { get; private set; }
    public ManualResetEvent DoneEvent { get; set; }
}

public class ClrSemaphoreWaitDemo
{
    static void Main()
    {
        const int numberOfTasks = 12;
        var doneEvents = new ManualResetEvent[numberOfTasks];
        var fibArray = new Fibonacci[numberOfTasks];
        ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(numberOfTasks, numberOfTasks);
        ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(numberOfTasks, numberOfTasks);

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTasks; i++)
        {
            doneEvents[i] = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            fibArray[i] = new Fibonacci {N= 4, DoneEvent= doneEvents[i]};
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(fibArray[i].ThreadPoolCallback, i);
        }

        WaitHandle.WaitAll(doneEvents);
        Debug.WriteLine("Now run .symfix; .reload; .loadby sos clr; !threads; !threads; !findstack clr!CLRSemaphore::Wait");
        Debugger.Break();
    }
}
```

When the debugger breaks, run the following command:

```
.symfix; .reload; .loadby sos clr; !threads; !threads; !findstack clr!CLRSemaphore::Wait
```

Comment: Hi Thomas  ,thank you so much for your kindly help for my several threads , I will check them one by one and then give the response.Thank you so much for you again.

Comment: Thomas , so it means just after the threadpool threads finished their work and before it got dead\destroyed, then they would call clr!CLRSemaphore::Wait to see if there is more work to do, and if they keep the that status and no more work to do in around  20 seconds, they would be dead\destroyed , right?

Comment: Basically yes, they are *wait*ing for new work through a semaphore that will be be set when new work arrives. In this state you can't tell whether they finished their work successfully or something went wrong (e.g. an exception happened). Regarding the 20 seconds: I actually don't know if they will be destroyed after some time. You could easily try that with the code above by adding a Sleep() call before the debugger break.

Comment: Thank you for your help for this topic, in my test, the threads would be destroyed after 20seconds if no work to do , and down to the 4 threads if I open such as 100 threads.

Comment: Hi Thomas , I got a similar issue in the thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44615400/why-we-need-to-check-the-isiopending-when-the-worker-thread-going-to-exit    and   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44615400/why-we-need-to-check-the-isiopending-when-the-worker-thread-going-to-exit , the threads increased to large number in short time just after a NETMON breathing  and those threads wouldn't exit after a long time, can you kindly help to check it?