# why the thread context is System.Runtime.Remoting.Contexts.Context?

Tags: c#, multithreading, windbg

This related to another thread [See lots of clr!CLRSemaphore::Wait in call stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38908668/see-lots-of-clrclrsemaphorewait-in-call-stack)  ,and we see lots of thread context is System.Runtime.Remoting.Contexts.Context ,we don't know why this happened.  how to simulate a thread with context System.Runtime.Remoting.Contexts.Context ?

```
0:030> !do 0000001fc0afc158  
Name:        System.Threading.Thread
MethodTable: 00007fffcd232140
EEClass:     00007fffccc6fa48
Size:        96(0x60) bytes
File:        C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll
Fields:
              MT    Field   Offset                 Type VT     Attr            Value Name
00007fffcd2ae6c8  4000765        8 ....Contexts.Context  0 instance 0000001fc0a80fe8 m_Context
00007fffcd248d40  4000766       10 ....ExecutionContext  0 instance 0000001cc0dcfc40 m_ExecutionContext
00007fffcd230bd8  4000767       18        System.String  0 instance 0000000000000000 m_Name
00007fffcd2332f0  4000768       20      System.Delegate  0 instance 0000000000000000 m_Delegate
00007fffcd2351d8  4000769       28 ...ation.CultureInfo  0 instance 0000000000000000 m_CurrentCulture
00007fffcd2351d8  400076a       30 ...ation.CultureInfo  0 instance 0000000000000000 m_CurrentUICulture
00007fffcd2311b8  400076b       38        System.Object  0 instance 0000000000000000 m_ThreadStartArg
00007fffcd234848  400076c       40        System.IntPtr  1 instance       208de67840 DONT_USE_InternalThread
00007fffcd2337c8  400076d       48         System.Int32  1 instance                2 m_Priority
00007fffcd2337c8  400076e       4c         System.Int32  1 instance               12 m_ManagedThreadId
00007fffcd22f370  400076f       50       System.Boolean  1 instance                0 m_ExecutionContextBelongsToOuterScope
00007fffcd23b9e0  4000770      378 ...LocalDataStoreMgr  0   shared           static s_LocalDataStoreMgr
                                 >> Domain:Value  0000001c3feb9a20:NotInit  000000208b6e4730:NotInit  <<
00007fffcd23bbf0  4000771        8 ...alDataStoreHolder  0   shared         TLstatic s_LocalDataStore
    >> Thread:Value <<
0:030> !do 0000001fc0a80fe8 
Name:        System.Runtime.Remoting.Contexts.Context
MethodTable: 00007fffcd2ae6c8
EEClass:     00007fffccd74ad8
Size:        104(0x68) bytes
File:        C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll
```

Comment: How to simulate a thread with remoting? The answer sounds obvious: implement some .NET remoting and let it be executed in a thread. What have you tried? Please show us your code.

Comment: Hi  Thomas, I found it when I used a framework , however I have no source code for it. I very appreciate if you can provide a sample code to reproduce that thread context.