# Why we need to check the IsIoPending when the worker thread going to exit?

Tags: .net, clr, windbg, coreclr

From the win32threadpool.cpp we know that before the worker thread going to exit by checking the 20s timeout, it need to check if there is any IO pending by method IsIoPending(),based on my understanding:

1,When the worker thread going to exit, it must finished it's work and return to the thread pool.

2,Based on the above 1, there should be no IO pending for the thread going to exit.

So my question is why we need to check the IO pending when the thread going to die? Alternative, how we can simulate the above condition happens?

```
RetryWaitForWork:
if (!WorkerSemaphore->Wait(AppX::IsAppXProcess() ? WorkerTimeoutAppX : WorkerTimeout))
{
    if (!IsIoPending())
    {




while (true)
{
RetryRetire:
    DWORD result = RetiredWorkerSemaphore->Wait(AppX::IsAppXProcess() ? WorkerTimeoutAppX : WorkerTimeout, FALSE);
    _ASSERTE(WAIT_OBJECT_0 == result || WAIT_TIMEOUT == result);

    if (WAIT_OBJECT_0 == result)
    {
        foundWork = true;
        counts = WorkerCounter.GetCleanCounts();
        FireEtwThreadPoolWorkerThreadRetirementStop(counts.NumActive, counts.NumRetired, GetClrInstanceId());
        goto Work;
    }

    if (!IsIoPending())
    {
```

https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/vm/win32threadpool.cpp

Comment: I didn't see the comments,can you kindly help to paste the comments here?

Comment: Did you refer the comments "// Returns true if there is pending io on the thread." ? Also what's the meaning  for "I/O is cache" ?

Comment: Perhaps I did not get everything yet. a) A thread from the thread pool is not going to die. It's being reused. b) By "we need to check" you mean the .NET framework does that for you. You need to do nothing when using the .NET framework. c) this seems to me like an XY-issue. Why do you want to simulate pending IOs? For unit testing?

Comment: I agreed with you that thread would be reused, however if it idle over 20 s, it would be destroyed , the CLR source code(if (!WorkerSemaphore->Wait(AppX::IsAppXProcess() ? WorkerTimeoutAppX : WorkerTimeout))) also described it  , please note WorkerTimeout is 20s; our issue is that our  threads idle over 10 hours, however didn't be destroyed ; we got that issue  which described in that  thread .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44617106/how-to-prove-there-is-io-pending-behind-the-thread-pool-worker-thread

Comment: @CodyGray: if the IO is in cache, the result is available immediately, isn't it? Why should it go into pending state at all then? Or do you refer to the IO operation pipeline e.g. on hard disk level? In that case I agree to Jason: why should the thread wait for it if the work is done and the result is never used?

Comment: Hi experts here, can you kindly help to check this  CLR debugging issue?    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44691232/got-the-error-symbol-clrxxx-not-found-when-debugging-the-clr-object-class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do a search for `IsIoPending` (which is one of the first things I do when encountering something that is unfamiliar to me), you'll see that a bit further down, it is called with the following comment preceding it:

> [`// We can't exit a thread that has pending I/O - we'll "retire" it instead.`](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/vm/win32threadpool.cpp#L3500)

That very nearly answers your question. Why do we need to check if a worker thread has any I/O pending before we allow it to exit? Well, because we cannot exit a thread that has pending I/O.

The only remaining question is, I suppose, *why not*? Why can't we exit a thread that has pending I/O? To investigate this, let's see what `IsIoPending` actually *does*. Search a bit further down the file, and you find [its implementation](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/vm/win32threadpool.cpp#L3916):

```
// Returns true if there is pending io on the thread.
BOOL ThreadpoolMgr::IsIoPending()
{
    CONTRACTL
    {
        NOTHROW;         
        MODE_ANY;
        GC_NOTRIGGER;
    }
    CONTRACTL_END;

#ifndef FEATURE_PAL
    int Status;
    ULONG IsIoPending;

    if (g_pufnNtQueryInformationThread)
    {
        Status =(int) (*g_pufnNtQueryInformationThread)(GetCurrentThread(),
                                          ThreadIsIoPending,
                                          &IsIoPending,
                                          sizeof(IsIoPending),
                                          NULL);


        if ((Status < 0) || IsIoPending)
            return TRUE;
        else
            return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
#else
    return FALSE;
#endif // !FEATURE_PAL
}
```

The comment doesn't tell us a whole lot here, other than confirming that the function is adequately named and that it does what we think it does! But what about its implementation?

Well, first thing you notice is that most of the interesting stuff is cordoned off by an `#ifndef FEATURE_PAL` conditional test. So what is `FEATURE_PAL`? PAL stands for **P**latform **A**daptation **L**ayer, and it is just a way of marking code that can work only on Windows. If `FEATURE_PAL` is defined, then the framework is being compiled for an OS *other* than Windows, so Windows-specific code needs to be excluded. And that's exactly what you see here—when `FEATURE_FAL` is defined, this `IsIoPending` function just returns `FALSE`. Only when it's running on top of Windows (when `FEATURE_PAL` is *not* defined) does it bother to check whether I/O is pending. This pretty strongly suggests that the comment above about not being able to exit a thread that has pending I/O is referring to a rule of the Windows operating system.

What happens if we're running on Windows? A call is made (indirectly, though a global function pointer) to the Windows API function [`NtQueryInformationThread`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684283.aspx). The first parameter passes a handle for the current thread (`GetCurrentThread()`), the second parameter requests the thread information class `ThreadIsIoPending`, and the next two parameters allow the function to fill in the `ULONG` variable `IsIoPending` (they pass its size and a pointer to it).

If you try to read the documentation for `NtQueryInformationThread`, you'll see that it's an internal function and that applications are advised to:

> Use the public function [`GetThreadIOPendingFlag`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683234(v=vs.85).aspx) instead to obtain this information.

The .NET source code doesn't follow this advice because that function (`GetThreadIOPendingFlag`) was not introduced until Windows XP SP1, and .NET 4 (and presumably older versions, for which this code was written) needed to run on downlevel versions of Windows. So they just called the internal function that was available on all supported versions of Windows.

Anyway, the documentation for `GetThreadIOPendingFlag` pretty much confirms it does what we would suspect what it does: it returns true if a thread has any I/O requests pending, or false otherwise. The internal function called by the .NET Framework implementation would return the same information.

And now I guess we're back to the original question: why does it matter whether a thread has any pending I/O? Why do we need to check this before we kill it? Well, in Windows, an I/O request issued by a thread is inextricably tied to that particular thread. There is no way to move ownership of this I/O request—or its resulting data—to another thread. Put differently, user-mode [IRPs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff550694(v=vs.85).aspx) cannot outlive the thread that originally created them. If the thread is exited, all pending I/O will be unceremoniously canceled and will never be completed. Thus, we get the rule stated so succinctly in the original comment: if a thread has pending I/O, it cannot be exited (because then that I/O would never be done and would be lost forever).

The `GetThreadIOPendingFlag` function (or `NtQueryInformationThread` with class `ThreadIsIoPending`) just checks the active IRP list for the specified thread to see whether or not it is empty. If no I/O requests are pending, then it is safe to exit the thread.

There are many reasons why a worker thread might have pending I/O requests, but the most common situation would be if an [overlapped (asynchronous) I/O request](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686358(v=vs.85).aspx) were issued by the thread. In this case, the timeout could elapse before I/O completion was signaled. Asynchronous I/O being dependent on the issuing thread is a fundamental limitation of the Win32 architecture, and the .NET Framework's implementation of the thread pool is aware of this limitation and accounts for it.

It may be that this check *typically* returns false, but it is a good idea to check it explicitly just to be on the safe side. These are standard defensive programming practices—a very important practice for a framework that is shipped worldwide, runs under a vast array of different conditions, and needs to be as robust as possible.

Comment: In fact,we got a issue described in that  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44617106/how-to-prove-there-is-io-pending-behind-the-thread-pool-worker-thread ,
after a network breaking, the num of worker threads increased to hundreds suddenly and never decreased , from !runaway 0x4 we found these thread lived for over 10 hours and in status  clr!CLRSemaphore::Wait+0x8a, just waiting for work.  So the only reason I can figure out is there is IO pending behind them ,otherwise these threads would be destroyed after idle 20s, the issue is how to prove there are IO pending from the memory dump?

Comment: Also I have a puzzle, the thread can also service for other new work item when there is a pending IO? from the source code we can see the thread waiting for the new work item coming to execute it.

Comment: Yes, sure it can. If the thread has to be kept alive anyway because it's waiting I/O, why not let it do other tasks while it waits?