# How to prove there is IO pending behind the thread pool worker thread?

Tags: debugging, windbg, coreclr

One of application have hundreds of thread pool threads pending with the call stack below after a network down;

BTW, before the network down, there is only dozens of threads, however after the network down, the number of threads increased to around 400 hundreds in very short time, and keeping that number unchanged for a very long time until we reboot the server.

```
00000020`a864fc58 00007fff`d4ea1118 ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0xa
00000020`a864fc60 00007fff`ce50ce66 KERNELBASE!WaitForSingleObjectEx+0x94
00000020`a864fd00 00007fff`ce50d247 clr!CLRSemaphore::Wait+0x8a
00000020`a864fdc0 00007fff`ce50d330 
clr!ThreadpoolMgr::UnfairSemaphore::Wait+0x109
00000020`a864fe00 00007fff`ce5de8b6 
clr!ThreadpoolMgr::WorkerThreadStart+0x1b9
00000020`a864fea0 00007fff`d60613d2 clr!Thread::intermediateThreadProc+0x7d
00000020`a864fee0 00007fff`d7be5454 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x22
00000020`a864ff10 00000000`00000000 ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x34
```

1, So why the threads increased to hundreds just after a network down , what's the possibilities?

Also in my understanding(also from the source code below !WorkerSemaphore->Wait...) the threads would be destroyed\exit after 20 seconds if no task assign to them From the call stack they were just waiting for the work and no task assigned to them , however those threads never got destroyed;
After checking the source code of CoreCLR, I noticed that the thread wouldn't be destroyed even after the timeout 20 seconds **if there is IO pending .**

2,So the question is how to check if there is IO pending for these threads by checking the user dump through winDBG?

https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/vm/win32threadpool.cpp

```
RetryWaitForWork:
if (!WorkerSemaphore->Wait(AppX::IsAppXProcess() ? WorkerTimeoutAppX : WorkerTimeout))
{
    if (!IsIoPending())
    {      
        DangerousNonHostedSpinLockHolder tal(&ThreadAdjustmentLock);

        counts = WorkerCounter.GetCleanCounts();
        while (true)
        {
            if (counts.NumActive == counts.NumWorking)
            {
                goto RetryWaitForWork;
            }

            newCounts = counts;
            newCounts.NumActive--;

            // if we timed out while active, then Hill Climbing needs to be told that we need fewer threads
            newCounts.MaxWorking = max(MinLimitTotalWorkerThreads, min(newCounts.NumActive, newCounts.MaxWorking));

            oldCounts = WorkerCounter.CompareExchangeCounts(newCounts, counts);

            if (oldCounts == counts)
            {
                HillClimbingInstance.ForceChange(newCounts.MaxWorking, ThreadTimedOut);
                goto Exit;
            }

            counts = oldCounts;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        goto RetryWaitForWork;
    }
```

BTW , these threads just created when the network down happened and lived for over 10 hours from the !runaway 0x4.

I just need a way to figure out why these threads never got destroyed even no work assigned to them over 20 seconds, the only reason I can figure out is there are IO pending behind those threads, however how to prove it?

Comment: "So why the threads increased to hundreds just after a network breaking , what's the possibilities?" -  this is question related to only specific, very bad design and written app. and impossible to answer without deep knowledge of this specific and unknown app

Comment: about `NtQueryInformationThread` with `ThreadIsIoPending` - this is obsolete begin from vista. this call simply check are `ETHREAD.IrpList` is emply. but now *Irp* can be queued not to thread but to `FILE_OBJECT`

Comment: formal, if kernel address space available in dump - we can look for `IrpList` of `ETHREAD` object - based on this and `NtQueryInformationThread` with `ThreadIsIoPending` return true (list not empty) or false (list empty). but only in xp/2003 io subsystem unconditionally insert Irp to this list (`IopQueueThreadIrp`) begin from vista in most case (depend from file type and how io operation is called (apc exist ? iocp binded ? user event ?) Irp can be queued to `FILE_OBJECT` instead - `IopQueueIrpToFileObject` - so now `ThreadIsIoPending` is unreadable way

Comment: Thank you RbMn, so it seems there is no way know the reason why the worker thread keeping on waiting , such as if it caused by the pending on IO or else?

Comment: I not study big source code. I say from general position. before vista every I/o operation was bind to thread (Irp for this operation was inserted to `Thread->IrpList`. but begin from vista - I/o can be bind to file object, instead thread. say if you use APC routine in io call - Irp will be bind to thread, if file have iocp and ApcContext !=0 - irp bind to file. if event object used in io call - depend are file opened in synchronous or asynchronous mode. [`IoPending = !IsListEmpty (&Thread->IrpList);`](https://github.com/bigzz/WRK/blob/master/base/ntos/ps/psquery.c#L3375)

Comment: this code actual and in win10 (unchanged) but now not all io related to thread

Comment: Does `!handle` show a high number of a certain handle type?

Comment: The  !handle Result is :
  Type          Thread
4341 Handles
Type                     Count
None                     92
Event                    2749
Section                  70
File                     182
Directory                3
Mutant                   8
WindowStation            2
Semaphore                135
Key                      56
Token                    7
Thread                   986
Desktop                  1
IoCompletion             6
Timer                    1
TpWorkerFactory          2
ALPC Port                8
WaitCompletionPacket     33

Comment: From the !threads there are  378 threads, around 340 worker threads have the same above CLR call stack.

Comment: I just need a way to figure out why these threads never got destroyed even no work assigned to them over 20 seconds, the only reason I can  figure out is there are IO pending behind those threads, however how to prove it?

Comment: RbMm, if the OS is vista or above, as the I/o can be bind to file object, instead thread , so there is no way to check if there is IO pending for a thread, right? If no , please tell me how to check there is IO pending for a thread even when bind to  file object.